# Form action url

Tags: php

Hi I'm currently using a dynamically generated url to produce a form action.  The output from PHP looks exactly like this `/home2/fortehom/public_html/richmindonline/testenvironment/process.php`.

The problem is that when I insert this dynamic url into the `action=""`, the url is being interpreted as `http://www.richmindonline.com/home2/fortehom/public_html/richmindonline/testenvironment/process.php`, which is incorrect.  I'm pretty sure this is because of the `/` at the beginning of the path.  I don't want to change the structure I already have in order fix this. Is there a way to remove the homepage from being added onto the front of the url?

Here's the code I'm using to generate the dynamic url if that helps:

```
function pluginpath() 
{ 
$base = dirname(__FILE__); 
$path = false; 

if (@file_exists $base)."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php")) 
{ 
    $path = $base."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php"; 
} 
else 
if (@file_exists $base."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php")) 
{ 
    $path = $base."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php"; 
} 
else 
$path = false; 

if ($path != false) 
{ 
    $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path); 
} 
return $path; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you actually want to do, but the behaviour that the domain is added to the `action=""` seem correct to me, ergo not a result of the `/` in the beginning of the path.

Propably you have a problem that `/home2/fortehom/public_html/richmindonline/testenvironment/process.php` is apparently outside of your website directory on the server. You should strip `/home2/fortehom/public_html/richmindonline/` from the path. In this way, you would receive `action="http://www.richmindonline.com/testenvironment/process.php"` which should be correct...

You can do this by adding a new line of code like this for example:

```
if ($path != false) 
{ 
   $path = str_replace("/home2/fortehom/public_html/richmindonline/", "", $path); 
   $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Michal, but I'm really having problems understanding this.  How could I strip the path down as you mention in your response?

Comment: I have edited my answer @Rob. It's a very basic approach, you should consider a more robust version using server environment variables. However, this should work for you for now...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your path "/home2/fortehom/public_html/richmindonline/testenvironment/process.php" is an absolute path to a file on your local filesystem. Your browser does not know what to do with this. You need to link to the file relative to your webroot. Something like this should work:

```
function pluginpath() 
{ 
  $base = dirname(__FILE__); 
  $_base = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],"",$base);
  $path = false; 

  if (@file_exists($base."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php")) 
  { 
      $path = $_base."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php"; 
  } 
  else 
  if (@file_exists($base."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php")) 
  { 
      $path = $_base."/wp-content/plugins/malware finder/process.php"; 
  } 
  else 
    $path = false; 

  if ($path != false) 
  { 
      $path = str_replace("\\", "/", $path); 
  } 
  return $path; 
}
```

Comment: Hi jasonlfunk, I echoed this function and nothing is being output. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just copied your code and make some changes without testing it. It turns out that you had syntax errors that I didn't notice. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you are making mistake in your action path. Basically you are trying to set full path of process.php but you need to set url.

For e.g. Form.php

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and action.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
    {
        echo $_REQUEST['name'];
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Here you can set action.php in form action or you can set http://localhost/action.php

I should suggest you to retrieve full url instead of full path. Use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].